# Error con consulta MYSQL de "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean..."

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente problema que me gustaría resolver,

Estoy haciendo una consulta con Mysql para sacar un dato llamado "estamento",

```html
        $query_estamento_usuario = ("SELECT 
                     estamento.nombre_estamento
                     from usuarios 
                     inner join estamento on estamento.id_estamento=usuarios.estamento
                     inner join alumno on usuarios.id = '".$row_id_usuario['id']."");
        $estamento_usuario = mysqli_query($con, $query_estamento_usuario);
        $row_estamento_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($estamento_usuario);
```

Y hago un "echo" para mostrar el dato estamento,

```html
 echo "El estamento del usuario es: ".$row_estamento_usuario['nombre_estamento']." ";
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar me aparece el siguiente error:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP5.3.0\www\capacitacion\cursos\ingreso_extra_usuario_bd.php on line 129

¿Cual puede ser el problema?, Saludos y muchas gracias,

Comment: puedes hacer un `if(!$estamento_usuario){ printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con))}` para validar la query!

Comment: Tu consulta tiene un error de sintaxis aquí: `inner join alumno on usuarios.id = '".$row_id_usuario['id'].""` debes usar `inner join` para unir tablas, no como si fuese un `WHERE`. Cambia por `inner join alumno on usuarios.id = alumno.laColumnaFK` donde `laColumnaFK` es la columna de la tabla `alumno` que une con la tabla `usuarios` y si hay que filtar por el valor de `$row_id_usuario['id']` debes poner esa condición al final: ` ... WHERE usuarios.id = $row_id_usuario[id]` puedes ponerlo así tal cual, pues para columnas numéricas no hay que encerrar el dato entre comillas simples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es por que tu query tiene un error quitale los `()` te falta cerrar una `'` al final (`$row_id_usuario['id']` puede ir sin comillas) y agrégale un control de errores para conocer mas a detalle sobre el posible error

Ejemplo:

```
$query_estamento_usuario = "SELECT 
                     estamento.nombre_estamento
                     from usuarios 
                     inner join estamento on estamento.id_estamento=usuarios.estamento
                     inner join alumno on usuarios.id = '".$row_id_usuario['id']."'";
        $estamento_usuario = mysqli_query($con, $query_estamento_usuario);
        if($estamento_usuario){
           $row_estamento_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($estamento_usuario);
        }
       else{
         var_dump(mysqli_error($con));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

La advertencia *`mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`* quiere decir que `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` está esperando un parámetro adecuado (un conjunto de resultados), pero está recibiendo un booleano. El error ocurre casi siempre porque al ejecutar `mysqli_query` estás obteniendo `FALSE` como resultado, debido sin duda a un error de sintaxis en la consulta. Otra cosa que podría provocar esto es que la conexión sea nula.

Para controlar ambas posibilidades evaluaremos el estado de la conexión y de la ejecución de `mysqli_query()` estableciendo un manejo adecuado de posibles errores en el código.

También (esto es ya una recomendación), evita declarar variables tan largas. En eso ayudaría quizá implementar una convención de nombres en inglés.

El código corregido quedaría así (me he permitido libremente modificar la convención de nombres para producir un código más estándar y más legible):

```
if ($con) {
    $sql="SELECT 
            e.nombre_estamento
          FROM usuarios u 
          INNER JOIN estamento e ON e.id_estamento=u.estamento
          INNER JOIN alumno a ON u.id = a.laColumnaFK
          WHERE u.id=$row_id_usuario[id]";
    if ( $stmt = mysqli_query($con, $sql) ) {
        $mData= mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt);
    } else {
        $mData=array( 'error'=>mysqli_error($con) );
    }
} else {
    $mData=array( 'error'=>'No hay conexión' );
}
#Devolver o usar $mData, aquí sólo hacemos una prueba
var_dump($mData);
```

OJO: en la consulta SQL, tienes que sustituir `laColumnaFK` por el nombre de la columna de la tabla `alumno` que une con la tabla `usuario`.

Si comparas este código con el tuyo, verás que he puesto el valor de `$row_id_usuario[id]` dentro de la cadena `$sql` así tal cual sin más. Esto es debido a que: 1º. los valores numéricos no deberían ir encerrados entre comillas simples en las consultas; 2º. como estamos dentro de una cadena entre comillas dobles, las claves de arrays se pueden escribir perfectamente así: `$array[clave]`, para evitar confusiones si metemos la típica comilla doble o simple que se usa habitualmente `$array['clave']` o `$array["clave"]`, en cuyo caso habría que concatenar.

---

> ### Nota sobre la seguridad
>
> Tu consulta SQL es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.
> Para evitarlo, deberías usar consultas preparadas para este tipo de
> consultas. Cuando sea posible, sin tardar demasiado, sugiero que te
> documentes al respecto. Los ataques de *Inyección SQL* pueden causar
> estragos en la base de datos y en el mismo sistema.